# CKEditor - Destroy an editor instance

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, instance, destroy

I created a page with some text, on click on a certain `DIV` an inline editor appears.

I need to destroy the newly created instance but I can't. I found in the [CKEditor  API the `destroy()` method](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-destroy)  but it doesn't work for me.
This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id ="0" contenteditable = "true">
    <h1Text</h1>
</div>

<div id ="1" contenteditable = "true">
    <h2>Other text</h2>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = false; //turn off automatic editor creation first 
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(idElem); //editor is the editor instance created
if(CKEDITOR.instances.editor != 'undefined' && editor != null) { 
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor.destroy(); //generates the error
}
```

The error is: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined**

In fact the following prints produce these results:

```
console.log("editor: " + editor); //prints "editor: [object Object]"
console.log("CKEDITOR.instances.editor: " + CKEDITOR.instances.editor); //prints "CKEDITOR.instances.editor: undefined"
```

Why? How can I get an editor instance just created so that it can then destroy?

Comment: `CKEDITOR.instances.editor != 'undefined'` - why quotes there? It's `undefined` actually. And can't you just use `editor.destroy()`?

Comment: @raina77ow `editor.destroy()` generates the same error

Comment: Can you show the HTML then? There's a limited set of elements which can be turned into CKEditor instances.

Comment: On the second thought, something is really wrong here: judging from [source](http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/inline.html#CKEDITOR-method-inline), `editor` can be either null or CKEditor instance, it shouldn't be `undefined` in any case. Can you debug `CKEDITOR.inline` to see what's happening?

Comment: @raina77ow I added the html post. Obviously the editor is associated with the DIV.

Comment: Just log the `editor` itself, with `console.log('editor: ', editor)`. It's an object, not `undefined` in any case, so recheck your code; you should at least see another error on `editor.destroy()`.

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks for the help. What do you mean with "`debug CKEDITOR.inline`"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90256/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-lonely).

Answer (score 0):

That (`CKEDITOR.instances`) is an array of instances you should loop it to destroy each one:

```
for (key in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[key].destroy(true);
}
```

Comment: this is something I need but it says this in the console: editor-incorrect-destroy

and after destroying it removes all ck editors + the official site states this issue as : The editor is being destroyed before it is fully initialized.

Comment: Still getting the warning : 
**[CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-incorrect-destroy.**